# Adding subdomain to another cPanel account

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, whm, add-on-domain

I have several cPanel accounts on my server (running Cloudlinux 5). I managed them using WHM.

My current situation (replacing the real domain with `example.com`):

Account A has an addon domain `example.com`.

Account B's primary domain is `sub.example.com`.

I want to add another sub domain `sub2.example.com` to Account B, so that it points to Account B's document root.

Now cPanel doesn't allow me to do so. It says `example.com` is owned by another user, which should be Account A, I guess.

Is there any way to point `sub2.example.com` to Account B's document root? I'm not asking for redirection from `sub2.example.com` to `sub.example.com`. The url `sub2.example.com` should not change.

What I have tried:

1. Add DNS record: `sub2 IN CNAME sub.example.com`.
2. Add `sub2.example.com` file to `/var/cpanel/userdata/AccountB`.

`sub2.example.com` just loads the server IP's default document root.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When cPanel adds a subdomain, it's a subdomain of the domain listed on the account. So, if account B has a primary domain of `sub1.example.com`, then it could only add domains like `sub2.sub1.example.com`. Somehow, you would want to be either making it into its own cPanel account, or adding it to the account with the primary domain `example.com`.

If you tried adding it to the userdata file, did you also `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf` and restart Apache? If you're showing the default IP, then Apache doesn't have a VirtualHost entry for that hostname and IP. You could probably hack it like that, though it isn't ideal.

If you must have the subdomains on account B, and the main site on account A, I would recommend changing the A to some other subdomain. I don't think that it could be `www.example.com`, thought that would be ideal. Maybe `www1.example.com`. Then, change B to `example.com`, with all the subdomains added there, and make `example.com` redirect to the subdomain which you are using for A.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. Besides adding the userdata file, I also have to modify the `main` file and include `sub2.example.com` as one of the subdomains. Rebuild and restart Apache. It works!